# Creating live template abbreviations/expansions for django in pycharm 4 doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, django, intellij-idea, pycharm

Django support is enabled for the project.  Under `Edit -> Settings -> Python Template Languages` Django is selected for HTML files. and under `Settings -> Editor -> Live Templates -> Django` I have created a new entry as follows:

```
Abbreviation: include
Description: {% include "" %}
Template text: {% include "$VAR$" %}
Expand with: Default (Tab)
Reformat according to style: unchecked
```

But when I try to expand this in the template, `include` becomes `<include></include>`.  I have tried restarting pycharm and the computer to no effect.  Have I misunderstood how to create an abbreviation expansion or is this a known bug?  Thanks.

OS: Ubuntu 14.04
Pycharm: 4.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under template's text "No applicatable context Define". Press Define and select "Django Templates"